# Replace White Spaces to "-" & uppercase to lower MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have 2 different field

`name` & `slug`

[image]

What I want to do is like for example on `row #18`

I have `name` value of `Full Process Microbiological Analysis`

and copied to `slugs` like this `full-process-microbiological-analysis`

As of now I can copy the value like this

```
 UPDATE services
 SET slug = name
 WHERE slug IS NULL OR slug = ""
```

But it only copy the value not modifying upper cases to lower cases and replacing whitespaces to dash(-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update services set
slug = replace(lower(name), ' ', '-')
where slug is null or slug = ''
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/159883):

```
select replace(lower('Full Process Microbiological Analysis'), ' ', '-')
```

returns

```
full-process-microbiological-analysis
```